# Rails: two Models have 'has_one' relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

If I want to have **Model has_one :model2**, and **Model2 has_one :model**, do I have to create join table then? Something like **model_model2**? And then tables would look like: **Model (id)** and **Model2 (id)** and **ModelModel2 (id, model_id, model2_id)** ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the relation field, tail will have `:dog_id` and dog will have `:tail_id`
Actually you can also create it using only 1 field, for example tail will have `:dog_id` and that's all, and then the relation would be

> dog has one tail
>   tail belongs to dog

And that's it.

If you want to try a marriage table in between, you'll need to create a join model `DogTail`

```
class DogTail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :tail
end
```

Then create a `has_one :through` relation

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :tail, through: :dogtail
end
class Tail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dog, through: :dogtail
end
```

Comment: I know belong_to/has_one relation. To your first sentence: Do you mean add ids and has_one relation to both models? I am asking cause I have been wondering if I can use has_one in two models(not: belong_to/has_on). ;-) just wondering what are the possibilities

Comment: I'm not sure if would become an invalid relation or not, but if you want to try it you should add the id fields to both models, then try `has_one` on both, and if it didn't work you can try `belongs_to` on both too.